# webkit: resize images in ratio

Tags: css, image, webkit, liquid

I´m using jquery mobile and Safari (iPad).
And I´m embedding one image like:

```
<img src="test.png">
```

So with CSS I´m trying to make this resonsive:

> ```
>       .ui-content img{
>           display:block;
>           border:1px solid #c8c8b9;
>           -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
>           -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
>           box-sizing: border-box;
>           max-width:100%;             }
> ```

The problem is, on webkit the width will be scaled correctly but the height will not change in ratio. So it will have the height like the image has full width but has for example only 80% of it.

How can I change this?

Comment: have you tried something?

Answer (score 0):

A technique to mantain the aspect ratio is to wrap the image in a container with `height: 0;` and a proportional `padding-bottom`

See this codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBpwF
In the example I picked a `1440x900`px image. Thus the height is `62.5%` of the width, so I used this css

```
div {
  border: 1px red solid;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1440px; /* the original image width */
  padding-bottom: 62.5%; /* the original height in % (1440 * 62.5% = 900px) */
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

As you can see if you resize the window, the image mantains correctly its ratio

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `height: auto;` to the CSS. That usually does the trick for me. Additionally, make sure no other CSS is affecting the dimensions of the image.

```
.ui-content img{
    display: block;
    border: 1px solid #c8c8b9;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;             
}
```